# Problematic declaration using inheritance in generics

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, interface

I have

```
LoginCommandExecutor implements CommandExecutor<LoginCommand>
LoginCommand implements Command
```

Why this line throws compilation error:

```
CommandExecutor<Command> a = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
```

But it works for both of followings:

```
CommandExecutor<? extends Command> a = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
CommandExecutor b = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
```

And if both are working, which one is preferable? Why?

because I see a and b reveals same methods in the IDE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
CommandExecutor b = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
```

uses a raw type. It should definitely not be used.

```
CommandExecutor<? extends Command> a = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
```

is correct, but hides the fact that what you have is actually a `CommandExecutor<LoginCommand>`. You won't be able to submit any command to this executor, since the type of command accepted by the executor is unknown.

```
CommandExecutor<Command> a = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
```

is wrong, since a LoginCommandExecutor only accepts LoginCommand, whereas `CommandExecutor<Command>` accepts any kind of Command. If that was accepted by the compiler, you could do

```
CommandExecutor<Command> a = new LoginCommandExecutor(commander, null);
a.submit(new WhateverCommand());
```

Comment: thanks. But isn't this contrary to the OOP inheritance?  `CommandExecutor<Command> a` exposes the base-class methods which `LoginCommand` implements anyway. No?
Not visa versa: It doesn't mean that `LoginCommand` can be casted to any class that inherits the base-class (aka `Command`)

Comment: LoginCommandExecutor is only able to handle LoginCommands. So you really don't want to be able to submit other kinds of commands to it. Just like you don't want to be able to store Integers into a `List<String>`.

Comment: I just don't get the difference in the declarations: `CommandExecutor<? extends Command>` and `CommandExecutor<Command>`

Comment: `CommandExecutor<Command>` means "a command executor that accepts any instance of Command". `CommandExecutor<? extends Command>` means "a command executor that accepts instances of an unknown subclass of Command". Since you don't know what the actual subclass is, you can't submit anything to the executor. You still can get commands from it though, since you know that they are all instances of a subclass of Command, and are thus instances of Command. Google "PECS".

Comment: `means "a command executor that accepts any instance of Command"` but that's still OK. `LoginCommand implements Command`. I want all of this to fill a Map with many commands

Comment: The point is: it accepts ANY kind of Command, not just LoginCommand. Whereas LoginCommandExecutor **only** accepts instances of LoginCommand. So a `CommandExecutor<LoginCommand>` is not a `CommandExecutor<Command>`: it can do **less** things than a `CommandExecutor<Command>`. A Mechanic<Vehicle> can fix any vehicle. A Mechanic<VolvoCar> can only fix volvo cars. So you can't bring your bycicle to a `Mechanic<VolvoCar>`, but you can bring it to a `Mechanic<Vehicle>`. a Mechanic<? extends Vehicle> fixes a specific kind of Vehicle: could be cars, or bicycles, or Honda motorcycles: you don't know.